# Scrolling of ListView in RefreshView is not working on an iOS devices - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I've been having an issue with the List View in Xamarin Forms not implementing their own default scrolling properly on iOS devices. I have created an application that has a List View and has lots of records List using inside it. But the list view is not allowing scrolling and I am not able to scroll all the items and not able to see or access all the items of the list especially the last elements of the list view. Whenever I try to scroll along with not allowing me to scroll it also jumps back to the top of the screen when I take my finger off the screen.

This issue happed on iOS devices and Xamarin Forms of the latest version , I have also checked to see if any of the previous versions of Xamarin Forms did not have this issue. But seems like almost all the versions have this issue and even i have checked on real iPhone devices.

Steps to Reproduce :
Create an app using the Xamarin Forms
Create List View in Refresh View and put lots of items model inside the List view, at least so many that you will need to scroll the list to see all items depending on the screen size.
Run app on device/ simulator with iOS
Start scrolling the list view

video for the issue - link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FLyy9MA_w-ranHufm9EUvGkxOGJt3nGa/view?usp=drive_link

codes

```
<RefreshView x:Name="MyRefreashView" Refreshing="RefreashView_Refreashing">
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasUnevenRows="False"  SeparatorVisibility="None"  ItemAppearing="ItemAppearingFunction" >
</ListView>
</RefreshView >

private async Task LoadingData()
{
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {

           ResposeData = Run_Async_GETALL(NumberOfRecords).Result;

   });

 _ListModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(ResposeData) as 
  List<Model>;

  

 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {

   ListView1.ItemsSource = _ListModel;
 });

}
```

Expected Behavior :
The List View that i have implemented should be scrollable and should be able to scroll the entire list and see all the items of the list on an iOS device. The scrolling behaviour should be normal as anywhere else the scrolling would work and should not jump back to the starting or top of the list.

Actual Behavior :
The List view does not implement or allow its default scrolling to work and because of this, I am not able to scroll all the items in the list. When I try to scroll down it scrolls partially and when I remove my finger from the screen it jumps back to the start/top of the list.

Comment: I can't determine the cause of your problem, please add more code for Page.xaml and Page.xaml.cs

Comment: hi, firt thank you for the replay , in page.xaml there is no code more than this code in the question
but in page.xaml.cs

this fucntion LoadingData();  loading data from api then change data from json to model
then put the model in the list by this code  ListView1.ItemsSource = _ListModel;

all thess is android its working fine , but in iOS cant scroll down ever, but when i remove RefreshView or let it IsEnable = false; the scroll working fine